# Ruby on rails guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For the guide that shows you how to set up a blog, I've gotten up to 5.7.
For this section it tells you how to show the article, but after following the steps I only get an error when attempting to run rails server.
It exactly says it is a syntax error in a routes line.
The line is `"article get /articles/:id(.:format) articles#show"` and the error is pointing to `:id`.
I'm not really sure what to do, I've looked at the routes section of the guide and I thought it was a valid line.

`routes.rb` contains

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
get 'welcome/index' 
resources :articles
root 'welcome#index' 
article get /articles/:id(.:format) articles#show
end
```

The exact message I receive when I use the command rails server is:

```
blog/config/routes.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) article get /articles/:id(.:format) article#show
```

Comment: Add the error appearing in the console and the `show.html.erb` file on articles.

Comment: Post your `routes.rb` file please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The route you're trying to make is bad formatted, I could say you literally pasted the output from the `rails routes` command.

You need to specify firstly the HTTP verb, `GET` in this case, then the `url` which this will respond with, and then the controller and action.

From:

```
article get /articles/:id(.:format) articles#show
```

Try with:

```
get '/articles/:id', to: 'articles#show'
```

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time. :) I did copy-paste, I thought that's what the guide was for!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've put in your description, it looks like you're at the very least missing a hash rocket (`=>`) in one of your routes. However, as you've added the `resources :articles` line, I think the line that's produced this error could probably be removed altogether as the `resources` keyword will generate common routes like these automatically (please see the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) for more details).

Your `routes.rb` file should probably just look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  resources :articles
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Alternatively, the route you're having trouble with could be rewritten as:

```
get "/articles/:id" => "articles#show"
```

or in the way described in the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

```
get '/articles/:id', to: 'articles#show'
```

Comment: Well yes (which is essentially what I wrote), but the OP is missing both of these...not to mention, the `articles#show` part of their route is missing quotation marks which I would also have expected to produce an error.

Comment: Kind of resent that you gave the winning answer to a guy who didn't even understand your question until after I'd answered it but I realise that's more the fault of the site than anything else. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove this line:

```
article get /articles/:id(.:format) articles#show
```

it should get ride of the error.

This line is not formatted correctly and it's trying to accomplish what is already being accomplished with the `resources :articles` line.